# Move array of DOM elements to placeholders in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a design received on my page with a set of placeholders such as:

```
  <span id="ApplicationDate_" class="removeMe"></span>
```

Plus other many elements as well inside that html. These spans should be replaced by real inputs coming from another area on the page, such inputs look like:

`<input type="text" id="ApplicationDate_48596977"/>`

So basically what I need to do, is to get all input elements in an array, and then for each element, get its ID up to "_", and search for the span that equals that value, and replace it with this element, then remove all spans with class=removeMe, but I can't achieve it in code, below is what I have reached:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var coll = $("input");
    coll.each(function () {
        var id = this.id; //getting the id here
        var substringId = id.substring(0, id.indexOf('_') + 1); //getting the span id
        this.appendTo("#" + substringId); //having problems here..
    });
    $(".removeMe").each(function () {
        this.remove();
    });
});
```

it tells me this.appendTo is not a function, any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: ``this.id``  is not correct you have to use ``$(this).attr('id');``

Comment: @hamism that's not true ... `this` is a dom node and `id` is a property of dom node

Comment: @hamism - Wrong.  `this.id` is preferred.

Comment: I don't get it, you are moving input to an element...then removing the element you just added it to...which also removes the input. Something doesn't seem right

Comment: I want to add content after the span, then I want to remove the span, the span is a placeholder where I want the element to be after.

Comment: `appendTo` won't work, use `insertAfter()`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR - Just use:

```
$(".removeMe").replaceWith(function() {
    return $("input[id^='" + this.id + "']");
});
```

---

Here's why:

`this` is a DOM element, but `.appendTo()` is a jQuery method.  You probably just need to wrap `this` in a call to jQuery:

```
$(this).appendTo("#" + substringId);
```

That would place the `<input>` element inside the `<span>` like this:

```
<span id="ApplicationDate_" class="removeMe">
    <input type="text" id="ApplicationDate_48596977"/>
</span>
```

But, then you call:

```
$(".removeMe").each(function () {
    this.remove();
});
```

First, you would have the same problem as above - `this` is a DOM element, but `.remove()` is a jQuery method.  Second, it would be better to just call `$(".removeMe").remove()` - wrapping it in a `.each()` is redundant.  Third, that would remove the span, and the input along with it.  That's not what you are trying to do is it?

If you want to replace the span with the input, use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith):

```
var coll = $("input");
coll.each(function () {
    var substringId = this.id.substring(0, id.indexOf('_') + 1);
    $("#" + substringId).replaceWith(this);
});
```

It seems like the whole thing could be rewritten, taking advantage of the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), as:

```
$(".removeMe").replaceWith(function() {
    return $("input[id^='" + this.id + "']");
});
```

Comment: is there a way to loop through all "controls"? I have input AND textarea, how do I go around this?

Comment: @DavidHemsey - You can separate selectors with a comma.  So, `$("input,textarea")` would match all input and textarea elements.